# Ajax call -> generates html -> next ajax call alter CSS of generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Scenario: First I generate some html based on a result from a ajax call.

This generated html will have buttons which will trigger a event.

When this event is triggered -> I submit another ajax call validating some input (on the 'newly generated html)

I get a response from this ajax call with some data.

SO FAR SO GOOD!

Problem:

Based on this result -> I want to alter my (newly generated html) by adding a class 'has-error / has-success'(to the newly generated html)

But jQuery can't find 'm since they weren't originally in the DOM.

NOTE:
adding .on events while generating the html / adding CSS while generating the html is not the issue!

I have to access them AFTER that

Comment: "But jquery can't find 'm since they weren't orignally in the DOM."  That is a false statement.  Sure, your bindings wont work because you are binding directly to the element.  Instead, create a wrapper which the newly generated HTML goes in to and bind on that using `$('#wrapper').on('click', '#newElement', function(){...});` instead.

Comment: Note:  Some people like binding do `$(document).on....` for this very reason, using the document as the "wrapper".  There is a small performance hit to this technique but negligible if there aren't too many bindings.

Comment: Please show the code for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of what I described in my comments.  You didn't give any html in your question so I'll just add a small bit.

```
<div id="container">(new html will go here)
    <span id="mySpan">this is my new span</span>
</div>
```

For your binding we will bind to the *container* which *is* there when the page first loads.

```
$('#container').on('click', '#mySpan', function()
{
    var $span = $(this);
    // some ajax call does something
    ...
    .success: function()
    {
         // or whatever you want to add             
         $span.addClass('has-error');
    },
    // whatever else your ajax has

});
```

In the future you should include code so that we don't have to be so vague with out answers.  That said, this is how you can accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Aye I figured it out by reading your first comment. -> upvoted but doesn't seem to work since I have low rep.

thank you mate!

Comment: Glad it helped.  I didn't put it in the answer since it wasn't part of the question but make sure the binding is wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function(){......});`.